# Wipe external storage doesn't work

Tags: android

Has anyone tried this flag for wipeData()?
I think [WIPE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#WIPE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) flag doesn't work because after calling the function, it will reset the phone to factory settings leaving the previous data on the external storage device. I hope someone can confirm about this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for wipeData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#wipeData%28int%29): External storage such as SD cards will not be erased. Also, the parameter currently must be 0. I've been wrestling with this issue as well and have found the only solution is to get the path from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and recursively delete directory contents.

Answer (score 2):

It is an existing issue in Android.

Refer: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65788

This works on some devices (I have tested with Samsung S4 and it works fine), but may not work in some (tried with Samsung S2 and SD card wipe failed, but the phone got factory reset).